# TypeError: Cannot create property 'FOO' on string 'BAR'

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

A wrong (and now fixed) code in our app triggered this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'FOO' on string 'BAR'
```

But Javascript completely allows setting free properties on a string variable. I just tried it in Chrome console :

```
'BAR'.FOO = 'hello'
'BAR'['FOO'] = 'hello'
```

And it works perfectly.

So in which context do the JS interpreter trigger this error ?

The original code is written in Typescript, then transpiled with Babel. This is a **runtime** error. I assume this is not related to typescript since other people report a similar runtime error, ex. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445517/cannot-create-property-type-on-string-radio-button-filters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258403/angularjs-cannot-create-property-method-on-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So in which context do the JS interpreter trigger this error ?

[Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

```js
'use strict';
'BAR'.FOO = 'test';
```

Comment: And Chrome console is not in strict mode by default... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';
var string = { name: 'bar' };
string.foo = 'hello';
console.log(string.foo + ' ' + string.name);
```